# What does "denn" mean in this context?

Tags: sentence-structure

Every so often, I see someone use "denn" in a question, but I do not know why.

Some examples:

> Was hörst du denn für Musik?
>
> Was machst du denn?

What is the point of this, and what does it mean? (I know *denn* means **because**).

Comment: I have done an in depths article on denn on my blog: http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2012/09/13/denn-meaning/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In these examples, **denn** is an adverb (also most often called a *modal particle*) and is similar in meaning to the English **then**.

It can *then* be translated like this:

**Then** what music do you listen to? (denn =then)

**Then** what do you do? (denn = then)

Comment: +1 since it actually is quite similar to the English *then*. But "Was machst du denn?" will very often have the meaning of "Whatever you do, it is completely nonsensical, cut it out." and this is more like "What the hell are you doing?" But this depends on context, of course.

Comment: @bouscher Of course. But the asker primarily wanted to know what _denn_ means. So I thought I could say exactly that, as found in any dictionary. As to the semantic nuances to which you've referred, I think they're impenetrable until the very first meaning of a word / expression is thoroughly mastered.

Comment: I think that is exactly, why it is a good question, because every learner will sooner or later stumble upon unexpected meanings of "denn", which no dictionary accounts for. But then again, every language has these kind of words.

Comment: @bouscher Then what do you mean when you say no dictionary accounts for it? The [English Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/denn) lists this, and there's an article on Wikipedia on [German modal particles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_modal_particle) (though they don't list *denn* in particular). And you gave a link yourself in your answer.

Comment: @Em1 I didn't say, there are no dictionaries, which give a meaning or explanation for it, I said, sooner or later one will stumble upon an occurence of *denn* with some sort of meaning, that no dictionary accounts for. Dictionaries can only do ever so much in trying to help to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Very good question. Since I didn't have a good explanation myself apart from *Füllwort- expletive* I found this: [Link](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adverb/Partikel/Modalpartikel.html)

So *denn* is a homonym which on the one hand can be a conjunction with a meaning of *because*, as you said.

On the other hand it is an adverbial modal particle, in German it has a special name *Abtönungspartikel*. This serves, I translate, to subtextually convey certain expectations or opinions of the speaker. It can give a statement or question a certain tinge.

A very common situation would be:

> "Ich höre Jazz."
>
> "Was? Echt?"
>
> "Wieso, was hörst du denn für Musik?"

In this case the last question has the subtext of: Whatever you now say, your kind of musical taste is inferior.

But the *Was hörst du denn für Musik?* can also be neutral or inviting in a different context.